# How to fix download notifications?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-touchwiz

From what it looks like, Facebook is just downloading an update, but it is not downloading anything. Even after multiple reboots and uninstalling Facebook app, it still continues. How to clear this up?

Phone is Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2. With default TuchWiz launcher.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: 
-Long pressing the notification. 
-A small dialog that says "App Info" will appear. 
-Press **"App Info"** 
-Press **"Force Stop"**.

Comment: I did the same and it fixed the issue. Also, cleared cache for this 'download' app. It was really frustrating to see this kind of issues..

Answer (score 0):

Just go in

**downloads**-->select **other downloads**( and it will appear `facebook build 141046`) -->select it -->click **cancel**

**OR**

**settings-->apps-->all-->download manager-->force stop**
disable and clear cache then enable again